# Avoid 304 HTTP status on redirect when logout occurs

Tags: http, spring-security, http-headers, http-redirect, response.redirect

I have a problem with HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(...), my scenario is:

I have a login.html page, when the user try to login and the credentials are wrong the server throws and exception and I redirect the user to the same page but with a URL param in order to show the error message from server, this is the line:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.html?error=message")
```

The problem is this:
The first time when I put the URL to enter the application and test the wrong credentials, this works very well, the error message is shown BUT, when I do logout calling:

```
http://localhost/app/j_spring_security_logout
```

And from server I catch the logout and I do:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.html");
```

And try to login with wrong credentials again, this isn't working because the browser catch the redirection as a NOT MODIFIED RESOURCE with a 304 HTTP code, so the login.html page is reloaded from cache and the message is not shown because the login action doesn't go to the server to validate the credentials.

I've tried changing the status code with:

```
response.sendRedirect("login.html");
```

It doesn't work yet.

There is a way to avoid this kind of behaviour?

Thanks so much!.

Comment: Never seen this. What gives a 304?

Comment: My server (Jetty) gives a 304 HTTP code which means: NOT MODIFIED

Comment: That is what I'm seeing on DevTools -> Network

Comment: It would be useful to see the exact request that generates a 304.